# Hacking Inside an Android Phone with PC & USB

Tags: usb, windows

Basicly, I completely **smashed** my phones screen. I am not really familiar with different screens, but this one is a 'fluid' kind and it blacked out my whole phone screen. I can charge the phone.

My mission here is to connect my phone (**Samsung S5 Neo**) to my laptop (**Windows 7**) and try to recover some pictures/files.

The phone is working fine. Just the screen is broken. The problem is that i have forgotten the password to open the lock on my phone and it would be very hard to type it in, since I can't see what I'm doing.

Is it possible to get the pictures/files from my phone without unlocking it?

What else could I do with otherwise functional phone with a broken screen?

Comment: Not likely... unless you had adb enabled and authorized for your PC prior to the screen breaking. Assuming you didn't have Google Photo automatically backing up your pictures, the best bet is to get the screen replaced.

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/samsung-4-left-in-rain-and-now-black-screen-can-i-recover-files/155123#155123) out... Not as simple as you would think.